# Display Count of records in excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I Have the below data in one excel Sheet

```
  Error Code                         type   object
-Ignored:31 Modified src data       *file   MINOSFIC/UTMNUP10
-Ignored:33 Modified src & tgt data *file   MINOSFIC/UVEGAP10
*Error:  08 Different data          *file   MINOSFIC/VM010P50
```

I need to count the records based on Error Code and put the data in same Sheet

```
ErrorCode  Count
Ignored    2
Error      1
```

I was trying Pivot table, but seems can't use it in existing excel sheet.

**Update:**

I am able to get the count using below code, but need help to put it in excel sheet in some table or some other way

```
$Excel = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Verify.xlsx" -WorksheetName "EDH_VFN"

$err = 0
$ign = 0
foreach($line in $Excel )
{
    $line_1 = $line.'Error Code'
    if($line_1 -match "Ignored")
    {
        
       $ign+=1 
    }
    if($line_1 -match "Error")
    {
    
        $err+=1
    }        
}

write-host "Error:"$err
write-host "Ignored:"$ign
```

Please need help in doing this

Comment: So where are you having trouble in your code?

Comment: You can use `COUNTIFS` with wildcards `*`.

Comment: @BigBen: COUNTIFS is an excel function if I am not wrong? I need to do it using powershell. Count i will get . but how to put that in existing excel sheet that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to do this with Excel function `COUNTIFS`, I would suggest simply exporting that Excel file to a CSV file which makes things a lot easier in PowerShell.

Example CSV file

```
Error Code,type,object
-Ignored:31 Modified src data,*file,MINOSFIC/UTMNUP10
-Ignored:33 Modified src & tgt data,*file,MINOSFIC/UVEGAP10
*Error:  08 Different data,*file,MINOSFIC/VM010P50
```

Once you have this, getting the count values could be done like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'X:\TheExcelToCsvExportedFile.csv' | 
    Group-Object @{Expression = {($_.'Error Code' -split ':')[0].Substring(1)}} | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'ErrorCode' ; Expression = {$_.Name}},Count
```

This will output:

```
ErrorCode  Count
---------- -----
Ignored        2
Error          1
```

you can simply copy/paste in that your Excel file anywhere you like.

Beware though that this does not comply with the columns you already have there..